# Export contacts from Yahoo! & Hotmail to Outlook 2007

Tags: yahoo, contacts, export, import, outlook.com

How can I export my contact lists in Yahoo! and Hotmail accounts to Outlook 2007? If you have done that before, was it easy and %100 percent successful (i.e. no missing or duplicate entries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yahoo Mail**

http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_export_my_yahoo_mail_address_book.html

It doesn't specifically talk about Outlook, but th option is clearly shown in a screenshot.

**Hotmail**

> If you do not have a Hotmail Plus subscription, which is required for this export process, you can export your Windows Live Hotmail contacts to a CSV file, from which in turn most email programs and services should be able to import your address book.

http://email.about.com/od/windowslivehotmailtips/qt/Export_Contacts_Email_Addresses_from_Windows_Live_Hotmail.htm

Answer (score 0):

A much easyer way is to use a hosted service like MemoToo and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx).

If you go to http://memotoo.com and setup an account you can have your contacts synced with tons of services including:

- Outlook
- Google Contacts
- Google Calander
- Facebook (One way)
- LinkedIn (One way)
- Windows Live Contacts
- Yahoo Contacts
- Twitter
- Windows Mobile
- Android
- Plaxo
- Soocial
- SheduleWorld
- UNYK
- Vodafone 360 (this is a realy crap service though)
- And tones more

Its also ver cheap and you only need to pay £12 per year if you have more than 50 contacts. I have 2000+ and it work just fine.

I did have a couple of hours of De-duping to do afterwords with so many services, but once you have sone that once all is good. Most dups can be deleted, but if you have a contact on Facebook and LinkedIn it is better to merge them. the service than knows to keep one for both serives.